# In a javascript case statement should I be putting multiple breaks or just one break when there's an if else?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two questions related to the code:

For my code should I have a break statement after each part of the if - else or just one at the end? Also when I define my object. Is it standard practice to be using uppercase for the fields such as Pk, Param, Table, Success?

```
    case "Exam":
        if (accountID) {
            obj = {
                pk: pk = accountID + "04000",
                param: '?pk=' + accountID + "04000",
                table: "Content",
                success: true
            };
            // break here ?
        } else {
            paramOnFailure("Please reselect Account");
            obj = {
                success: false
            };
            // break here ?
        }
        // break here ?
```

Comment: I don't understand the dilema. They both do the same thing. Do whichever appeals to you most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
case "Exam":
    if (accountID) {
        obj = {
            pk: pk = accountID + "04000",
            param: '?pk=' + accountID + "04000",
            table: "Content",
            success: true
        };
    } else {
        paramOnFailure("Please reselect Account");
        obj = {
            success: false
        };
    }
    break; // break here
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you'll be `break;`ing no matter what, you should put the `break;` after the last block. And as for the naming conventions, no, the convention isn’t uppercase. Lowercase is fine

Answer (score 1):

A single break at the end of each case should be sufficient , As the last statement of the particular case block will hit no matter unless it is returned..

Using smallcase is a standard practice in javascript. If you have multiple words in your variable name then use camel casing to give a clear picture.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion,
1. `break;` can be used once, at the very last line
2. Fields such as Pk, Param, Table, Success don't use them as uppercase